# Function with "auto" or template type deduction: "no matching function for call to..."

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compiler-errors, auto

Suppose I have the function:

```
void mergesort(auto first, auto last) {
    if(last - first > 1) {
        auto middle = first + (last - first) /  2;
        merge_sort(first, middle);
        merge_sort(middle, last);
        std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last);
    }
}
```

And I want to use `mergesort` as an argument for another function (also returning `void`).

After reading some other SO questions, I have tried the following:

```
void sort(auto args, std::function<void (auto, auto)> sorter) {
    // some stuff
    sorter(args.l.begin(), args.l.end());
    // some other stuff
}
// called by:
sort(args, mergesort);
```

And also.

```
void sort(auto args, void (*sorter)(auto, auto)) {
    sorter(args.l.begin(), args.l.end());
}
// called by:
sort(args, mergesort);
```

The above attempt I also tried changing around the pointers, etc. just in case I was forgetting anything.

None of these work, and they return the error:

```
no matching function call to 'sort(p_args<long double>&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

The `args` argument is a templated struct, and it works fine, I am having trouble with passing the function `mergesort`.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `auto` as a function parameter type is not allowed by any C++ Standard.  (It was possible in some versions of the Concepts proposal, but the version of Concepts accepted a while back for C++2a does not permit it either.)

I believe g++ has some support for using `auto` as a function parameter type as a compiler extension.  All this really does is convert a function into a function template, where each `auto` is replaced with a template type parameter.  But that only applies to actual function declarations and function definitions.  Creating a pointer to function `void (*)(auto, auto)` or a `std::function<void(auto, auto)>` will not work even with this compiler extension, because in both cases you need a specific function type, not some sort of template.

So you should probably change your code to just explicitly use templates to be portable:

```
template <typename Iter>
void mergesort(Iter first, Iter last) { /*...*/ }

template <typename Args, typename Func>
void sort(Args& args, Func&& sorter) {
    std::forward<Func>(sorter)(args.l.begin(), args.l.end());
}
```

(Note I'm assuming you'd be okay with forcing the same deduced type for both parameters of `mergesort`, although I believe g++ would treat the original `void (auto, auto)` declaration as two independent types.)

Comment: If I try to call it using `sort(args, mergesort)` it still gives the same errors. Should I be using `mergesort` with any pointers? If I try `sort(args, *mergesort)` it gives the error: `overloaded function with no contextual type information`.

Comment: @f0YtHQ4 Write `void sort(Args& args, void (*sorter)(decltype(args.l.begin()), decltype(args.l.end())))`

Comment: @PasserBy So I need to write another function just to call this function? I'm lost.

Comment: @f0YtHQ4 I meant to change the declaration of `sort`, the error says `no contextual type information`, so you provide it

Comment: @PasserBy That didn't fix the errors, if I write that and use `sort(args, mergesort)` or `sort(args, *mergesort)` it still gives the  `overloaded function...` error.

Comment: @f0YtHQ4: `mergesort` is not a function, it is a **template** function, so you have to specify which one you want `sort(args, &mergesort<decltype(args.l.begin())>)` or wrap it in a functor as lambda: `sort(args, [](auto b, auto e) { mergesort(b, e); });`